# Finding total days worked by employee from current date or interval from there hire date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck on a query wherein for a employee I am trying to find the total no of days he has worked from the hire date or any date interval for that matter ie it should return the total days

I did the query to find employees who have worked fro 100 days from a date interval

```
 select first_name,salary,hire_date, from employees
 where 
  hire_date + to_dsinterval('10 10:00:00')<= date'2003-01-01';
```

How do I modify it to return total no of days?

I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition HR schema.

for the time and tip

Comment: you can subtract days `where SYSDATE - hire_date >= 100` also select it: `select ..., SYSDATE - hire_date as no_days`

Comment: hi danihp thxs didnt strike that i shud first try to subtract it with sysdate thank you so much its working now

Comment: I find it easier to read (and understand) using an `interval` literal rather than `to_dsinterval()`: `interval '100' day`

Answer (score 1):

the solution would be if to find from a particular date total days worked query would be

```
select first_name,salary,hire_date,(date'2003-01-01'-hire_date)  totaldays 
from employees
where 
hire_date + to_dsinterval('10 10:00:00')<= date'2003-01-01';
```

and all the working days to the current date

```
select first_name,salary,hire_date,round((sysdate-hire_date))  totaldays 
from employees
where 
hire_date + to_dsinterval('10 10:00:00')<= date'2003-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

To return total days between two dates:

```
SELECT empno, hr_date, (end_dt - hr_date) days_btwn
  FROM
(
 SELECT empno, hiredate hr_date, trunc(sysdate) end_dt
   FROM scott.emp
)
/

-- Same as above --
SELECT empno, hiredate
     , trunc(sysdate)  today
     , (trunc(sysdate) - hiredate)  days_btwn
  FROM scott.emp
 /

EMPNO    HIREDATE    TODAY    DAYS_BTWN
----------------------------------------
7369    12/17/1980    5/9/2013    11831
7499    2/20/1981     5/9/2013    11766
7521    2/22/1981     5/9/2013    11764
7566    4/2/1981      5/9/2013    11725
...
```